# Equivalence between definitions of purely inseparable extension

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field, separable-extension

I was doing some algebra today and I came across the term 'purely inseparable extension'.
However, I came across two different definitions of this term.
We consider algebraic extensions and write $p$ = char($K$). The definitions go as follows:

> A field extension $E/K$ is purely inseparable if and only if for every $x \in E\setminus K$ the minimal polynomial of $x$ over $K$ is not separable.

> A field extension $E/K$ is purely inseparable if and only if for every $x \in E\setminus K$ there exists an $n$ such that $x^{p^n} \in K$.

To help convince myself that these different difinitions make sense, I tried to proof the equivalence between them. So I tried to prove the following:

> For every $x \in E\setminus K$ the minimal polynomial of $x$ over $K$ is not separable if and only if for every $x \in E\setminus K$ there exists an $n$ such that $x^{p^n} \in K$.

However, I have not been succesfull in this endeavour. Can someone help me with this please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: To begin with, do you assume the field extension to be algebraic? Otherwise, minimal polynomial doesn't make sense. Also, you should mention that you want to prove that in characteristic $p$. (as your $p$ is not just some random prime)

Comment: @Mark Sorry, I indeed assume the field extension to be algebraic. Thanks for your comment, I made the necessary edits.

Comment: See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/359497/11619). Alas, that old question is unanswered in a sense. The comments do shed additional light.